# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

Tengo un problema con los **Arrays** en el siguiente **ejercicio**:

Necesito que el programa pregunte el número de países, lea cuántos países ingresa el usuario y que después pida 3 ciudades por cada uno y los imprima en pantalla. El numero de ciudades siempre sera el mismo.

Con el codigo actual me aparece este **error**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 at 
Paises.main(Paises.java:20))
```

**Mi código** es:

```
    public static void main(String args []) {
    int p=0;
    int c=3;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Digite el numero de paises: ");
    p = sc.nextInt();
        String [][] arrMulti =new String[p][c];
        String ax="";
        
        for (int i=0;i<p;i++){
            System.out.print("Introduce el nombre del pais "+(i+1)+" : ");
            arrMulti[i][0] = sc.nextLine()+":";         
        }
        for (int j=0;j<3;j++){
            for (int i=1;i<4;i++){
                System.out.print("Introduce el nombre de la ciudad "+(i)+" del pais "+(j+1)+" : ");
                arrMulti[j][i] = sc.nextLine();             
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
                ax+= arrMulti[i][j]+"        ";
            }
            ax+="\n";
        }
        System.out.print(ax);
    }
```

Comment: Por favor, indica qué falta en tu código, qué problema tienes, por qué dices que estás atascado? Edita tu pregunta usando la opción [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/386606/edit) que está justo debajo  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me gustaría hacerte algunas recomendaciones:

1. Utiliza nombres de variables significativos. Tener variables que se llaman `p`, `c`, `ax` hacen que el código sea difícil de leer. Una estrategia que sigo desde hace mucho tiempo es ayudar a mi cerebro a invertir su limitada energía en cosas que valgan la pena, como entender el algoritmo que está reflejado en el código y no tratar de memorizar para qué se usa `p`, o `x`. Esos nombres están bien para variables de control de ciclos, que no tienen realmente ningún significado y se usan solo en dos o tres líneas del código, pero no para uso generalizado. Escribir `p` o `cantidadDePacientes` toma más o menos el mismo tiempo, pero procesarlo cerebralmente toma mucho menos esfuerzo en el segundo caso.
2. En mis primeros años en la programación solía recurrir con mucha frecuencia al papel. Cuando ya no era capaz de seguir con un algoritmo, iba al papel y realizaba la ejecución paso a paso, llevando a mano el valor de las variables. Eso me permitió alcanzar un mejor nivel de abstracción y me dio una gran habilidad para realizar el proceso mentalmente.

Finalmente, dado que este es un ejercicio del colegio, no quiero entregarte el ejercicio ya resuelto, pero he hecho uno bastante similar que pide los nombres de personas y sus aficiones.

Espero que al leerlo notes la diferencia del uso de nombres significativos en las variables. He añadido algunos detalles, como la palabra reservada `final` en la declaración de la constante `MAXIMO_AFICIONES`, lo cual indica al compilador que su valor no va a variar durante toda la ejecución del programa, y he descartado la línea vacía que queda en el scanner luego de hacer la llamada a `nextInt()` llamando a `nextLine()` y descartando el resultado.

El orden para pedir los datos, ha sido intercalar el pedido de personas y sus aficiones, antes de pedir el nombre de otra persona y sus aficiones. Cambiar este orden, una vez entiendes la lógica que está detrás, debiera resultarte trivial.

```
public static void main(String args []) {
    int maximoPersonas;
    final int MAXIMO_AFICIONES = 2;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("¿Cuántas personas vamos a procesar?: ");
    maximoPersonas = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();

    String [][] personasYAficiones =new String[maximoPersonas][MAXIMO_AFICIONES + 1];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < maximoPersonas; i++){
        System.out.print("Introduce el nombre de la persona "+(i+1)+": ");
        personasYAficiones[i][0] = sc.nextLine();         
        for (int j = 1; j <= MAXIMO_AFICIONES; j++) {
            System.out.print("Introduce la afición No. "+(i+1)+" de " + personasYAficiones[i][0] + ": ");
            personasYAficiones[i][j] = sc.nextLine();         
        }
    }

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Personas y sus aficiones");
    for (int i = 0; i < maximoPersonas; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= MAXIMO_AFICIONES; j++) {
            System.out.print(personasYAficiones[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Mi recomendación es que, a estas alturas de tu aprendizaje, no simplemente copies y pegues el código. Copiar y pegar está bien, pero si he hecho un ejercicio que no es exactamente el mismo, es para ayudarte a tomarte el tiempo de entender su funcionamiento y adaptarlo a lo que necesitas, más allá de una simple sustitución de texto, espero que aproveches la oportunidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias @jachguate, me sirvió bastante conseguí adaptarlo a mi ejercicio y funcionó perfecto, un abrazo!!

Comment: Excelente, espero que te haya quedado más claro. Juega con el código, haz adaptaciones, eso te ayudará a avanzar. Bueno, es lo que yo hice alguna vez... de hecho, todavía lo hago cuando estoy aprendiendo cosas nuevas.

Answer (score 1):

Encontré algunos bucles que desbordaban, además al no limpiar el `Scanner` después de hacer un `nextInt()` cuando leías los nombres de las ciudades la primera siempre salía en blanco, te dejo el código arreglado y en los comentarios algunas explicaciones.

```
public static void main(String args []) {
        int p=0;
        int c=3;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Digite el numero de paises: ");
        p = sc.nextInt();
        //Cuando usas nextInt() se queda el retorno de línea en el buffer de manera que a la próxima vez que leas
        //algo con nextLine(), leerás primero una línea vacía. Para limpiar el buffer simplemente usa
        sc.nextLine();//No hace falta guardar este valor, solo queremos limpiar el retorno que se quedó ahí!
        String [][] arrMulti =new String[p][c];
        String ax="";

        for (int i=0;i<p;i++){
            System.out.print("Introduce el nombre del pais "+(i+1)+" : ");
            arrMulti[i][0] = sc.nextLine()+":";
        }
        for (int j=0;j<p;j++){//Para introducir ciudades, tendrás que hacerlo hasta p, que es el número de paises que tienes!
            for (int i=0;i<3;i++){//Tenías el bucle con i=1;i<4, tiene que ser 0 y 3! Los array siempre empiezan en 0
                System.out.print("Introduce el nombre de la ciudad "+(i+1)+" del pais "+(j+1)+" : ");
                arrMulti[j][i] = sc.nextLine();
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<p; i++){//Tenías este bucle idéntico al de arriba, con 3 y 4 en vez de p y 3
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
                ax+= arrMulti[i][j]+"        ";
            }
            ax+="\n";
        }
        System.out.print(ax);
    }
```